# Why is style.left not returning a value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check the left co-ordinate of a div but it's not returning any value. When I try to check the left value in alert() it shows a blank. Can you help??

Browser is Firefox 8.0

Comment: post your html and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only give you the CSS property `left`. If you want to get it's actual coordinates, use `getClientRects`.

```
var rects = document.getElementById("#myDiv").getClientRects(); //This returns a set of rectangles representing the element
var rect = rects[0]; //There is usually only 1 rectangle
alert(rect.left);
```

Note that you should not use `alert` for debugging. That's what `console.log` is for. You can then see the output in Chrome's console or in Firefox if you have Firebug installed. `alert` can be misdirecting as it will format certain things. It is also a lot more annoying to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you set that value in css and not using the inline style attribute. You should use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: Wow, I had never heard of that. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because you haven't set `style.left` or set a CSS `left` property in the `style` *attribute*.

`element.style` maps directly onto the style attribute. It does not give you computed style.

See [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) for that. If you want to see the left position, as opposed to the value of the CSS `left` property, then see [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft).